# Sylius\Component\Grid\Definition\Filter::setPosition() must be of the type integer, string given

Tags: symfony, sylius

In sylius the filter setPosition give Error:

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Component\Grid\Definition\Filter::setPosition() must be of the type integer, string given

```
filters:

    empty_filter10:
      type: empty_filter10
      position: 99999991
```

From where can it will be set as integer